# Installing and creating a configuration for GRUB (Ubuntu 18, RAID1, LVM). Problems

Tags: grub2, lvm

There is my config (VirtualBox):

```
    sda                   8:0    0   10G  0 disk
├─sda1                8:1    0  512M  0 part  /boot/efi
└─sda2                8:2    0  8.5G  0 part
  └─vg0-lv0         253:0    0  8.5G  0 lvm   /
sdb                   8:16   0   15G  0 disk
├─sdb1                8:17   0  512M  0 part
└─sdb2                8:18   0 14.5G  0 part
  └─md0               9:0    0 14.5G  0 raid1
    └─datavg-datalv 253:1    0 14.5G  0 lvm
sdc                   8:32   0   15G  0 disk
├─sdc1                8:33   0  512M  0 part
└─sdc2                8:34   0 14.5G  0 part
  └─md0               9:0    0 14.5G  0 raid1
    └─datavg-datalv 253:1    0 14.5G  0 lvm
sr0                  11:0    1 50.5M  0 rom
```

Now my system boots successfully, I see GRUB menu.
I'm doing a system disk transfer from lv0 to datalv.
After that I ran into a problem installing GRUB and creating a config file for it.

How I did:

```
sudo mount /dev/datavg/datalv /mnt 
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/boot/efi

sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev &&
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts &&
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc &&
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys

sudo chroot /mnt

grub-install --target=x86_64-efi /dev/sdb

grub-install --recheck /dev/sdb

exit &&
sudo umount /mnt/sys &&
sudo umount /mnt/proc &&
sudo umount /mnt/dev/pts &&
sudo umount /mnt/dev &&
sudo umount /mnt
```

After that, I disconnect the system disk (sda) and try to boot from sdb.
Unfortunately I get a broken GRUB. I see the just grub> console (not resque).

I want to install GRUB on 2 disks sdb1 and sdc1 and specify in grub.cfg that my system is on LVM (datavg/datalv).

Please point out my mistakes to me. What am I doing wrong?
Am I going to have to clone sda1 and manually edit that awful file grub.cfg?

Thanks!

Comment: Grub normally installs to ESP - efi system partition on first drive. Check your fstab.  I prefer to have an ESP on every drive, but not required. You also cannot have duplicate UUIDs. But if RAID, I assume then duplicates are allowed?

Comment: ```
fdisk /dev/sdb или sdc for 1 partition:
```

         Device: /dev/sdb1
          Start: 2048
            End: 1050623
        Sectors: 1048576
           Size: 512M
           Type: EFI System
```
However, on
```
grub-install /dev/sdb
```
i get installation to sda disk.

The only thing I want to do is to make new the config file for a specific disk like /dev/sdb, sdc
```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```
But it doesn't work even when I do a chroot.

Comment: If you are getting grub install to sda, then your fdisk has the UUID of an ESP on sda. Change fstab to have UUID of ESP you want, then run `sudo grub-install` and it will use ESP in fstab.